# Purpose of 'there' after 'to intend'?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Source: p 48 , *The Law of Contract*, 5 ed (2012), by O’Sullivan and Hilliard

> For example, if my (happily married)
>   wife and I sit down to carefully decide who should pick up the kids from school on
>   which day, and I say that I will do it on Mondays and Tuesdays if she does it on the other
>   weekdays, it does not appear to my wife that I intend our arrangement to impose legal
>   obligations upon either of us. It is not a situation in which we believe that there will be
>   further negotiations following which we enter into a legally binding arrangement; we
>   never intend **there** to be a contract at all.

Since ['intend' can be transitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/38380/8712), why **there**? Why not simply write 'we never intend a contract at all'? My Googling produced [p 214, Oxford Modern English Grammar, by Bas Aarts](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=7ryuRtiasPYC&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=%22intend+there+to%22&source=bl&ots=qDX5OAjZD5&sig=tf8Xt7SrL4nWB_S88V_rrP4Lsms&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z9lYVN23A8TtmgWTsIG4CA&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22intend%20there%20to%22&f=false) which I don't understand:

> The grammaticality of the following example [38] also shows that the 
>   postverbal NP position cannot be filled by an argument of INTEND.
>
> 38 I certainly **intend** there to be an increase in ranger and warden ser- 
>   vices to ensure that responsibities are exercised by those who have 
>   the new right.
>
> As noted before, **there** (along with dummy *it*) is meaningless, and 
>   cannot therefore be a semantic argument of the verb that precedes it.

Comment: There's not really a *why*.  That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as *for there*, dropping the preposition:

> we never intend **(for) there** to be a contract at all.

and

> I certainly intend **(for) there** to be an increase in ranger and warden services...